# How to replace a LONG string of text in a column that is dtype object in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df ("data") full of information from IMDB, and I'm trying to replace the string of text for unavailable synopses with a NaN. I wanted to start by simply counting them, using this code:

```
data[data['synopsis'=='\\nIt looks like we don\'t have a Synopsis for this title yet. Be the first to contribute! Just click the "Edit page" button at the bottom of the page or learn more in the Synopsis submission guide.\\n']].count()
```

But, I get a key error. I have a hunch it's because of the dtype?

I've tried to convert the synopsis column from object into string, to no avail, using this code:

```
data['synopsis'] = data['synopsis'].apply(str)
```

and this code:

```
pd.Series('synopsis').astype('str')
```

But when I look at the info, nothing changes. I was able to convert startYear to datetime, though.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 27007 entries, 0 to 31893
Data columns (total 17 columns):
 #   Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------               --------------  -----         
 0   tconst               27007 non-null  object        
 1   titleType            27007 non-null  object        
 2   primaryTitle         27007 non-null  object        
 3   originalTitle        27007 non-null  object        
 4   isAdult              27007 non-null  int64         
 5   startYear            27007 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 6   endYear              27007 non-null  object        
 7   runtimeMinutes       27007 non-null  object        
 8   genres               27007 non-null  object        
 9   storyline            20362 non-null  object        
 10  synopsis             27007 non-null  object        
 11  countries_of_origin  26640 non-null  object        
 12  budget               11295 non-null  object        
 13  opening_weekend      771 non-null    object        
 14  production_company   19478 non-null  object        
 15  rating               13641 non-null  float64       
 16  number_of_votes      13641 non-null  object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), int64(1), object(14)
memory usage: 4.7+ MB
```

I'm new to all this--what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the bracket in the wrong spot in your filter line. You want to close `df[df['synopsis']==...]`.

And I believe that pandas uses `object` as the dtype for strings, so it is correct for it to say `object`.